# Getting color property value as hex value

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the color property of an element using:

```
getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(
    "color"
  );
```

which gives me the rgb color code, **Is there a way to get this in hex format?** since I am traversing the whole DOM so I want to save some effort of converting each of them to hex value using some custom function.

***Edit***: I have gone through the other answers, but that's not what I am looking for. I want to get it from the element rather than converting all of them later on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb

Comment: I know about all these solutions, I don't want to do it for each and every element when I am traversing through the DOM.

Comment: "*I want to get it from the element rather than converting all of them later on.*"  a) you can't b) what difference would it make? How would your code look when you used that solution (please post it), and what is the problem with that?